# How do I block temporarily block react-router route changes in Redux-Saga?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

My user onboarding flow is:

1. user authenticates thru google & is flagged `isRegistrationDone: false`
2. user confirms profile information, clicks `save`
3. `save` throws `redux action REGISTRATION_COMPLETE`, profile sets to `isRegistrationDone: true`

In my `sagas`, i check for the `isRegComplete: false` flag. if it's detected, i want all user route changes to redirect to `/reg`

```
function* fetchUserProfile(action) {
  const { uid } = authUser
  const path = getRootPath('userProfiles')
  let userProfile = // retrieve from database

  if (userProfile.isRegistrationDone === false) {
    browserHistory.push('/reg')
    yield call(watchRouteChanges)
    let confirmedUserInfo = yield take(REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)
    // ... write to database
    yield cancel(watchRouteChanges)
  }

  browserHistory.push('/dash')
}

function* watchRouteChanges() {
  fork(takeEvery, LOCATION_CHANGE, redirectToRegistration)
  return
}
function redirectToRegistration(action) {
  const destination = action.payload.pathName
  if (destination !== '/reg') browserHistory.push('/reg')
  return
}
```

this works `hunky-dory` until `yield cancel(watchRouteChanges)`, which throws:

```
utils.js:191 uncaught at sagas 
 at takeEvery 
 at fetchUserProfile 
 Error: cancel(task): argument function watchRouteChanges() {
      return _regenerator2.default.wrap(function watchRouteChanges$(_context2) {
        while (1) {
          switch (_context2.prev = _context2.next) {
            case 0:
              (0, _effects.fork)(_reduxSaga.takeEvery, _location.LOCATION_CHANGE, redirectToRegistration);
              return _context2.abrupt('return');

            case 2:
            case 'end':
              return _context2.stop();
          }
        }
      }, _marked[1], this);
    } is not a valid Task object 
(HINT: if you are getting this errors in tests, consider using createMockTask from redux-saga/utils)
    at cancel (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:27590:12)
    at fetchUserProfile$ (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:27992:39)
    at tryCatch (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:26312:41)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:26586:23)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:26345:22)
    at next (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:28480:28)
    at Object.currCb [as cont] (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:28554:8)
    at end (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:28521:24)
    at Object.task.cont (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:28331:12)
    at next (http://192.168.0.103:3000/app.1b8181c5bf9c72be8a4e.js:28490:36)log @ utils.js:191end @ proc.js:299abort @ proc.js:95task.cont @ proc.js:108end @ proc.js:305abort @ proc.js:95task.cont @ proc.js:108end @ proc.js:305abort @ proc.js:95task.cont @ proc.js:108next @ proc.js:281currCb @ proc.js:338end @ proc.js:305task.cont @ proc.js:115next @ proc.js:274currCb @ proc.js:338checkEffectEnd @ proc.js:579chCbAtIdx @ proc.js:594currCb @ proc.js:338
```

The redirection logic appears to work fine, but I of course need to cancel it to make this process work.

Is there a better way to do this? or a mistake in my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cancel` effect expects tasks descriptor as an argument, not a function/generator or whatever else. In your case:

```js
...
if (userProfile.isRegistrationDone === false) {
    browserHistory.push('/reg')
    const task = yield call(watchRouteChanges) // <-- Save task descriptor
    let confirmedUserInfo = yield take(REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)
    // ... write to database
    yield cancel(task) // <-- Pass descriptor for cancellation
}
...
```

Please, checkout the docs: http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/index.html#canceltask